# Is it possible to add custom icon to outlook such as follow up icon using redemption

Tags: outlook-redemption

Is there way add custom icon to outlook  as following image using redemption  ?

[image]

Updated-

But outlook is allowed add icon using custom form.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the appearance of that icon cannot be customized.